# How stable are paper book matches?

Tags: combustion

I have few hundred paper book match books that I collected about 25 to 45 years ago when many businesses had them custom printed.
They are from around the world although mostly US. They are in an open glass container in a closet. I am asking is there is any risk of them igniting with age

Comment: *Today I learned* aficionados of [safety matches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match) follow their hobby of [phillumeny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phillumeny).  Some of them enjoy exchange on [r/phillumeny](https://www.reddit.com/r/Phillumeny/) -- maybe they can provide some insight from a practical perspective?  Worth to check Wikipedia's editions in other languages, too.

Comment: https://siarchives.si.edu/blog/their-heads-matchbooks-archives may prove useful.